# Is it okay to use the Present Perfect tense twice in the same sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, present-perfect

I wonder if it is grammatically fine to use two `have/has been` in the same sentence?

**Example:**

> After you have been informed that your paper has been accepted…

Comment: Those perfects are passive, not continuous. And they're fine.

Comment: @Rathony. How does it not look fine? And what is the relevance of one being before the other? It looks fine to me.

Comment: Without the main clause that this clause is subordinate to, there's not enough present  context to see why one might prefer perfect to past. All variants in _After [having been/you have been/you were] informed that your paper [is/was/has been/had been] accepted, ..._  are grammatical and meaningful, but they don't always match up with the clause they modify.

Comment: It's not a sentence yet. It's just a subordinate clause; and either the past tense or the perfect construction -- or both -- can be used, depending.

Comment: But it's easier to understand the **sentence** with _after_; it's the only actual reference to relative time in the clause. There are rules for changing _after_ clauses into participles, but they're much less clear.

Comment: To me, the text as given seems more natural than with _was_. But, as John Lawler says, it depends on the context and the intended meaning.

Comment: Too many 'have beens' . If you want a clean style it should read 'after you have been informed your paper is accepted.' No need for grammar analysis clutter here. We're looking for a concise style, not a treatise on grammar.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically fine. There could be two "has/ have been" in a sentence. Grammar does not prohibit this.

Answer (score 1):

These clauses are in passivised present perfect. Without the main clause, it cannot be decisively told whether the sentence is correct or not. However from the '...' we may safely presume that that there is a satisfactory principal clause that brings this sentence to its logical ending.

It is often hotly argued against too much use of passive but up until now those two subordinate adverb and noun clauses in passive present perfect are fine.